# Suggest a best practice to create Constants class

Tags: c#, class

There is a debate between my team members about the declaration of a Constants class. We are moving the constant variables into a separate class like below.

```
public class Constants
{
      public const string StateId = "ST";
      public const string CountryId = "CI";
}
```

A few of my team members suggested that we declare the class as sealed to avoid overriding option, and a few are suggesting that we mark it as static to avoid instance creation of the Constant class.
However, I prefer to have it as Sealed with a static constructor, since it will help us to initialize the read-only variables in future need.
Please give us some advice on this.

Comment: Whichever what you go, one consideration could be to use an interface in the system rather than the constants class itself to avoid dependencies between the objects and a "Global" type class???

Comment: So you agree on making the class static and just asking if you should add a static constructor now or later? I don't see any opposing opinions in your question, please clarify.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)**

Comment: I don't get your question. If a class has no instance members, you can mark it `static`. This is completely orthogonal to the presence or absence of a static constructor.

Comment: Are your constants actually constants in the mathematical sense, or is this a form of configuration?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's not totally clear what your question is, but if the values are truly constant, I don't see a problem with the simple option of:

```
    public static class LocationConstants
    {
        public const string StateId = "ST";
        public const string CountryId = "CI";
    }
```

Using `static` in the class declaration signals your intention for the purpose of this class.

Marc Gravell describes some of the potential issues with constants in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/755693/3195719). Only you will know if these are a problem in your codebase, but if the values *could* ever change, use `public static readonly` instead of `const`, else any code referring to the constants will need to be rebuilt if the values change.

Comment: One of the caveats you can find using const variables is clearly explained [here](http://www.stum.de/2009/01/14/const-strings-a-very-convenient-way-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot/). Since codebases tend to grow and get more complex, it is better to avoid using `const`, the performance gain is usually not worth the risks of potential trouble in the future, IMHO. I prefer to use `public static readonly` variables for constants.

Comment: @joanlofe, what do you mean by "variables for constants"? aren't the terms "variable" and "constant" mutually exclusive?

Comment: @jarmanso7 I realize that phrase does not convey well what I wanted to say. It should be rewritten as "I prefer to use `public static readonly` for constants", but I cannot edit my comment.